# TogglerBar and Legend color mismatch

Tags: plotting, manipulate, color, legending

I have this piece of code

```
XuColor = {Red, Green, Blue};
XuNames = {"cat", "dog", "rat"};

fun2 = Thread[{Sin[x], Cos[x], Tanh[x]} -> XuNames];
Manipulate[
 Legended[Plot[fs, {x, 0, 3 Pi}, PlotStyle -> XuColor], 
  Placed[LineLegend[XuColor, XuNames, LegendLayout -> "Row"], 
   Below]], {fs, fun2, ControlType -> TogglerBar}]
```

However the Legend is displaying the wrong colours (rat should be the tanh function in blue etc.)
The colour of the curve actually depends on the order with which I click the toggler. If I have only the rat curve then it is displayed with the correct color (second image)
How do I fix this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: `fs` order/content is affected by your actions while `PlotStyle` setting stays the same and independent of those actions.

Comment: Any idea on how to fix this directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an `Association` to do this as follows:

```
fun2 = <|"cat" -> {"color" -> Red, "f" -> Sin[x]}, 
         "dog" -> {"color" -> Green, "f" -> Cos[x]}, 
         "rat" -> {"color" -> Blue, "f" -> Tanh[x]}|>;

Manipulate[
 Legended[
  Plot[Evaluate["f" /. (fs /. fun2)],
   {x, 0, 3 Pi}
   , PlotStyle -> ("color" /. (fs /. fun2))
   ],
  Placed[LineLegend["color" /. (Keys@fun2 /. fun2), Keys@fun2, LegendLayout -> "Row"], Below]]
 , {fs, Keys@fun2, ControlType -> TogglerBar}]
```

Which will 'automatically' keep the ordering correct.

---

If you prefer to keep the same structures you'll have to make a slight modification

```
XuColor = {Red, Green, Blue};
XuNames = {"cat", "dog", "rat"};

fun2 = Thread[{Sin[x], Cos[x], Tanh[x]} -> XuNames];
Manipulate[
 Legended[
  Plot[
   Evaluate@Keys@fun2[[fs]],
   {x, 0, 3 Pi},
   PlotStyle -> XuColor[[fs]]
   ],
  Placed[LineLegend[XuColor, XuNames, LegendLayout -> "Row"], Below]
  ],
  {
   {fs, 1},
   Table[i -> XuNames[[i]], {i, Length@XuNames}], 
   ControlType -> TogglerBar
  }
 ]
```

This way `fs` chooses an integer but uses your labels, and you takes the appropriate part of each list where needed. Unless `fun2` needs to be in the form it's in, I'd suggest just making it a list of the functions without the mapping to names. Then you can drop the `Keys` function.

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping to keep the structure of the code more similar to the one I have, because this is only a reproducible example part of a larger notebook. But your solution works