# Preserving the colours with Manipulate

Tags: plotting, manipulate, color

I am trying to get the correct colors for my curves. I have this code

```
color = {Red, Green, Blue};
names = {"cat", "dog", "rat"};
Manipulate[
 Legended[
  Plot[Sin[k x], {x, 0, 3 Pi}, PlotStyle -> color[[k]]], 
  Placed[LineLegend[color, names, LegendLayout -> "Row"], 
   Below]], {{k, {1, 3}}, {1, 2, 3}, ControlType -> CheckboxBar}]
```

Which instead of assigning `color[[k]]` (red green and blue) to each curve, it assign the same colour to every curve.

[image]

I have already asked a [similar question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/158949/togglerbar-and-legend-color-mismatch) and there is [a post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/27131/plotstyle-in-listplot-change-color-scheme-manually-choose-color-of-first-plot) which does exactly this, though for a `ListLinePlot` (last image). I've tried so many different things but none really does the trick.

It is kind of important that I do this in the most simple way because this is a MWE part of a bigger script. In particular I would like to keep the flexibility to increase the number of colors/names without having to modify anything inside the `Manipulate`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `Evaluate@Sin[k x]` will handle this issue.

```
color = {Red, Green, Blue};
names = {"cat", "dog", "rat"};
Manipulate[
 Legended[Plot[Evaluate@Sin[k x], {x, 0, 3 Pi}, 
   PlotStyle -> color[[k]]], 
  Placed[LineLegend[color, names, LegendLayout -> "Row"], 
   Below]], {{k, {1, 3}}, {1, 2, 3}, ControlType -> CheckboxBar}]
```

[image]

Comment: I can't believe it's as easy as that. I've spent a day trying to solve this. Why do I have to `Evaluate` it to have the correct colors?

Comment: @Manfredo check this https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1731/plot-draws-list-of-curves-in-same-color-when-not-using-evaluate